# Scaling Image in Python makes it darker

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

Good day,

I have an image which I generate through a deep learning process. The image is RGB, and the values of the image range from -0.28 to 1.25. Typically I would rescale the image so that the values are floating point between 0 and 1, or integers between 0 and 255. However I have found that in my current experiment doing this has made my images much darker. The image type is np.array (float64).

If I plot the image using matplotlib.pyplot then the values of the original image get clipped, but the image is not darkened.

[image: correct image, but clipped]

The problem with this is that I am unable to save this version of the image. plt.imsave('image.png', art) gives an error.

When I scale the image I get the below output which is **dark**. This image can be saved using plt.imsave().

[image]

Here is my scaling function:

```
def scale(img):
    return((img - img.min())/(img.max() - img.min()) * 255)
```

My questions:

1) Why I am I not able to save my image in the first (bright) image? If scaling is the problem, then:

2) Why does scaling make the image dark.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Why am I not able to save my image in the first (bright) image?

It's hard to answer this without seeing the specific error you're getting, but my guess is it might have to do with the range of values in your image. Maybe negative values are an issue, or the fact that you have both negative floats and floats larger than 1.

If I create some fake RGB image data in the range `[-0.28, 1.25]` and try to save it with `plt.imsave()`, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Floating point image RGB values must be in the 0..1 range.
```

> 2) Why does scaling make the image dark?

Scaling your image's pixel values will likely change the appearance.

Imagine you had a light image, such that the values in the image ranged from `[200, 255]`. When you scale the values, you spread the values from `[0, 255]` and now you have pixels that were previously bright (around `200`) being mapped to black (`0`). If you have a generally bright image, it will seem darker after scaling. This seems to be the case for you.

As a side note: I would suggest using Pillow or OpenCV rather than Matplotlib if you're doing lots of image-related work :)

**EDIT**

As @alkasm pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58834467/scaling-image-in-python-makes-it-darker/58835036?noredirect=1#comment103945457_58835036), when you use `plt.imshow()` to display the image, the values are clipped. This means that the first image will have all negative values mapped to 0, and all values greater than 1 mapped to 1. The first image is clipped and saturated to make it appear that there are more dark and bright pixels than there should be.

So it's not that the second image is darker, it's that the first image isn't displayed properly.

Comment: Note: "Out-of-range RGB(A) values are clipped." from https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html so OP's image is actually taken to be [0..1] in `imshow()` --- so all the negative values map to 0 and all the values >1 get mapped to one. OPs image is thus "clipped" or "saturated" at the ends which is why it's got more brights and darks than when they map the full range---NOT because the image got shifted up in intensity (brighter).

Comment: The clipping should only occur when it's displayed with ```plt.imshow()```, though, so I'm not sure that would affect the image values that are scaled.

Comment: Right, that's what OP states. I'm simply stating the reason for the contrast difference after scaling in this case is because of clipping in `imshow()`.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were talking about the second image. Great point, I've made an edit.

Comment: Great, nice answer!